# Determine filesystem path of current JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Inside of a JSP page, I was to determine the current path of the page on the file system, for example:

```
WEB-INF/jsp/currentPage.jsp
```

I want to be able to jsp:include to another page that is based on the current filesystem path, not the URL the user is using to access the page.

I want to be able to copy/paste the same code to many JSPs and have each page know its filesystem path.

Comment: This seems like very bad practice. Don't go outside the app scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863248/get-current-filename-in-jsp). Basically, you can use regular expressions on this.getClass() to determine the full path.

In the JSP:

```
<jsp:include page='<%= SkinController.getSkinPath(this.getClass() ) %>' />
```

And in SkinController.java

```
public static String getSkinPath( Class<?> cls ){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("org.*INF.?.(jsp|tiles).(.*?)_jsp");

    String name = cls.getName();

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);

    if( matcher.matches() ){
        String type = matcher.group(1);
        String path = matcher.group(2).replace(".", "/");

        //fullPath is the value we're looking for int he original question
        String fullPath = type.concat("/").concat(path).concat(".jsp");

        return getSkinPath(fullPath);
    }else{
        return "";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For referencing other jsp pages (and for other utility methods for JSP), use the JSTL library. Very handy. You can look at [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm) for reference on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use geturi method on request:

```
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
String pageName = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: That will return the path to the [root of the servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-mean-in-the-method-servletcontext-getrealpath), I want the path to the current JSP page.

I want to be able to copy/paste the same code to many JSPs and have each page know its filesystem path.

Comment: get uri and parse it to know your jsp page.

Comment: That doesn't do it either since the JSPs are included into other JSPs. I need the actual filesystem path, not pull it out of the request URI.

Comment: What exactly you need then? Can you add example in your question as well?